# The sum of 50 terms of the series $\frac{3}{1} $+ $\frac{5}{1+2^2} $+ $\frac{7}{1+2^2+3^2}$+ $\frac{11}{1+2^2+3^2+4^2}$...

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

The numerator is increasing by 2.
The number of terms in denominator is increasing, and they are squares of natural numbers (i.e. $1^2, 2^2, 3^2, 4^2...$)

Options are:

(a)$\frac {100}{17}$
(b)$\frac {150}{17}$
(c)$\frac {200}{51}$
(d)$\frac {50}{17}$

Comment: @Darth Geek Not exactly. The number of terms in the denominator is also increasing...

Comment: No, the denominator is in it's own sum.

Comment: I would conjecture (Thank you Mathematica) that $S_n = 6 - 6/(1+n)$ and you're looking for $S_{50}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start by simplifying the denominator of the $n^{th}$ term.

$$U_n=\frac{2n+1}{\sum_{i=1}^ni^2}$$

$$=\frac{6(2n+1)}{n(n+1)(2n+1)}$$

$$=\frac{6}{n(n+1)}$$

$$=\frac{6}{n}-\frac{6}{n+1}$$

So the sum of the first 50 terms will be:

$$S_{50}=U_1+U_2+U_3+\cdots+U_{48}+U_{49}+U_{50}$$

$$=\frac{6}{1}-\frac{6}{2}+\frac{6}{2}-\frac{6}{3}+\frac{6}{3}-\frac{6}{4}+\cdots+\frac{6}{48}-\frac{6}{49}+\frac{6}{49}-\frac{6}{50}+\frac{6}{50}-\frac{6}{51}$$

$$=6-\frac{6}{51}$$

$$=\frac{100}{17}$$

Comment: Oh my god! I made a very silly mistake. Thanks for the workout. I really appreciate it. :)