# The sum of $\frac{1^3}{1} $ + $\frac{1^3+2^3}{1+3}$ + $\frac{1^3+2^3+3^3}{1+3+5}$... to 16 terms.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I couldn't get the answer for this. 
Options are $\ 246, 646, 446, 746$

I tried doing $\sum n^3 $ / $\sum2n+1  $  *

*My mistake was taking the denominator as 2n+1, even though it was 2n-1.

Comment: So what did you learn from your [last question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2006796/the-sum-of-50-terms-of-the-series-frac31-frac5122-frac7)? Please reflect upon that and have a go at this one as they are very similar in approach.

Comment: Try writing down the first few terms explicitly, and look for a pattern.

Comment: @IanMiller You say sum of first odd numbers is $n^2$. Isn't it $n^2+2n$ ?  By doing $\sum (2n+1)$ ?

Comment: Your denominator isn't quite right. It should be $2n-1$.

Comment: I hate myself. I always make these kinds of silly mistakes :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  1^3+2^3+\ldots+k^{3} &= \frac{k^2(k+1)^2}{4} \\
  1+3+\ldots+(2k-1) &= \frac{k[1+(2k-1)]}{2} \\
  &= k^2 \\
  \frac{1+\ldots+k^3}{1+\ldots+(2k-1)} &= \frac{(k+1)^2}{4} \\
  \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1+\ldots+k^3}{1+\ldots+(2k-1)} &=
  \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(k+1)^2}{4} \\
  &= \frac{1}{4} \sum_{k=2}^{n+1} k^2 \\
  \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2 &= \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} \\
  \sum_{k=1}^{16} \frac{1+\ldots+k^3}{1+\ldots+(2k-1)} &=
  \frac{1}{4} \times \left[ \frac{(17)(18)(35)}{6}-1 \right] \\
  &= 446
\end{align*}

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** The sum of the first $n$ cubes is $\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2$. The sum of the first $n$ odd numbers is $n^2$.

Comment: @HarshaG. This plus your last answer should give you plenty to get this done. Why don't you try posting an answer to your own question.

Comment: @IanMiller I got it simplified to $\frac {(n+1)^2}{4}$. But putting 16 as n, doesn't get me the answer...

Comment: That is only the $n^{th}$ term. You still need to do the sum from 1 to 16.